# MATLAB code error

Tags: matlab

I have written this function in matlab

```
function [A] = intmat(a,b,N)
 M = length(a);
 A = zeros(M,N);
 for m = 1 : M
   for n = 1 : N 
     my_func = @(t) (t^(N-n));
     A(m,n) = quad(my_func,a(m),b(m));
   end
 end

end
```

Now when i use this function for a = [1 2 3 4 5] and b = [1 2 3 4 5] and N = 5
i.e is run the statement intmat(a,b,N). i get the following error.

**??? Error using ==> mpower**

**Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.**

**Error in ==> intmat>@(t)(t^(N-n)) at 6**

**my_func = @(t) (t^(N-n));**

**Error in ==> quad at 77**

**y = f(x, varargin{:});**

**Error in ==> intmat at 7**

**A(m,n) = quad(my_func,a(m),b(m));**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a .^ instead of ^ for writing equations which involve vector operations in MATLAB. Vote to close as it seems to be a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
my_func = @(t) (t^(N-n));
```

to:

```
my_func = @(t) (t.^(N-n));
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange error, because in my MATLAB it is showing:

> Error using  ^  Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix. To
>   compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.

Where answer is hidden in error message. You must apply element-wise operation. By default when for vector you do `a*a` it will compute dot product. In order to multiply element by element use: `a.*a`. So change the line 6:

```
my_func = @(t) (t.^(N-n));
```

Last question - what your software is supposed to do? Calculate integral for different ranges?

Comment: it is calculating a matrix A such that y = Ax. 
where y[m]= integral (f(x)) ranging from am to bm. And f(x) is polynomial of Nth order.

Comment: btw which matlab version are you using?

Comment: @user128806: The version is 2014a. I see what you are trying to do, but not fully convinced is it a correct way, i.e. your code will produce different size of output matrices for different values of `N`. Although I presume that from this point you can debug and make your code run.

Comment: yeah it would give different size. but would satisfy dimension in y = Ax.